# NAT without impact on already created static NAT entries

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat

We already have one-to-one (private to elastic) IP mappings for external reachability. But, also, it's mandatory to create a NAT (PAT - private IPs to one PUBLIC IP) but without impacting already configured one-to-one entries. Is it possible ?

The problem is that we need NAT, but NAT should't involve in already used one-to-one IP bindings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The 1:1 mappings for EIPs are provided by the Internet Gateway, which is the target of the default route on public subnets.

The NAT Gateway, itself, is *created* on one of these public subnets (so that it has access to the Internet Gateway) but never provides dynamic NAT (PAT) services for instances on the subnet where the NAT Gateway itself is located.  It provides service for instances on *other* subnets -- different, private subnets,  and you assign the NAT Gateway as the default route in the route tables for those private subnets.

The NAT Gateway does not interfere with the 1:1 mappings provided by the Internet Gateway.

Comment: thank you, so my mistake was - that i changed the default route for all my private subnets from IGW to NAT. And it started to route everything through NAT instance. So route table is working only with with subnets which is associated with that routing table, right ? And the only way to separate Elastic IPs 1:1 mappings from NAT (PAT) is to user another private subnet. Yes ? :) Also, could you answer my other question here about VPC dynamic routes here:  https://serverfault.com/questions/874906/checking-vpc-routing-table Thank you very much:)

Comment: 1:1 EIP static NAT requires a *public* subnet, which is defined as a subnet with the IGW as its default route.